# How to handle the CRLF in bcp utility. using bcp to restore the csv file into Azure SQL database. File is comma delimited and content with ""

Tags: azure-sql-database, bcp, data-import

I am facing issue while importing the data in azure sql database using bcp utility.

```
bcp dbo.Account in "D:ABC\Account.csv" -S xxxxx.database.windows.net -U jfsa -P xxxxxx -d dbname -a 4096 -b 50000 -k -E -h "tablock" -q -c -l 120 -t "," -r "0x0d0x0a" -o "D:\Logs\FileLog\account_output.txt" -e "D:\Logs\Error\account_err.txt" -m 100 -F 2
```

Contents in account csv
[image: Sample SCV file]

Not getting any error but below message after running the command

Starting copy...

0 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1

Comment: You are being mislead: Despite the examples in MS's documentation, `bcp` cannot actually handle "real" CSV files. BCP requires files to have a specific binary format, it only supports trivial CSV files by sheer coincidence.

Comment: Thanks @Dai, can you please tell what is specific binary format.  can you suggest any alternate way to import the above csv file into Azure SQL database.

Comment: I cannot make any recommendations without knowing what tooling and languages you're currently using. But my preferred approach (in C#) is to use the `CsvHelper` NuGet library to fill a `System.Data.DataTable` which is passed into `SqlBulkCopy`. I suppose you could try using _Azure Data Studio_'s "Flat file importer", but it's a very basic tool that still has plenty of bugs...

Comment: Thanks,  I was also thinking the last option as coding in C# but before that trying if can get it done via some shorter way.

Answer (score 0):

> Restore the csv file into Azure SQL database.

- You can use SQL server management studio to load the csv file to sql database. Follow the steps in this document [How to import a CSV file into a database using SQL Server Management Studio-discountasp.net](https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1179/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-a-database-using-sql-server-management-studio.aspx).
- You can also use **Copy activity** in azure data factory to copy csv data into sql database. Give csv file as source dataset and SQL database table as a sink dataset in copy activity.

As @Dai suggested, you can also use c# with the use of `CsvHelper` NuGet library to fill a `System.Data.DataTable` which is passed into `SqlBulkCopy`. I used that approach as you can see below.

**Below are the steps I followed:**

- **Connection String** is used to connect with Azure SQL Database. **tableName** and **csvFilePath** is used to store the Table name and .csv file path.
- `StreamReader` is created to read the CSV file and `CsvHelper` is used to parse the csv data.
- Each record in the CSV is an instance of  **DataClass**. The `ToList()` method is used to read all records from the CSV.
- `DataTable` named `dt` is created to match the structure of the SQL table. It is configured with columns according to the structure of the data.
- `SqlBulkCopy` is used to insert the data from the `DataTable` into the Azure SQL Database.

**Below Is the code I tried with:**

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string connectionString = "*****";
    string tableName = "SampleTable"; 
    string csvFilePath = @"C:\Users\****\Desktop\****\SampleDataFile.csv";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(csvFilePath))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
        {
            var records = csv.GetRecords<DataClass>().ToList(); 
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));

            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(record.Id, record.FirstName, record.Age);
            }

            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Data imported successfully.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Data Stored in CSV file:**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]